# Indication of different times

Tags: tense, past-tense, present-tense, future-tense, time

1. I am very happy to have helped you.
2. I'm very happy to be helped you.
3. I'm very happy to help you.
4. I was very happy to had helped you.

By the first sentence, I wanted to mean that I've helped someone right now, and I am happy for this.

By the second sentence I meant that I helped someone before, now I'm happy for this.

By the third sentence, I wanted to mean that I'll be happy if I get a chance to help you. Can I rewrite the third sentence in the following way without changing its meaning?

- I'll be very happy to will have helped you/I will be very happy to help you/I'll be very happy to have helped you.

By the fourth sentence, I mean, I helped someone before, and in past I was happy for this.

Please tell what you think about my examples and about my explanation. If any correction is needed, please prescribe me.

Comment: I think the 3rd sentence does not imply "I would be happy to help you" !

Answer (score 1):

Let's analyse the cases:

> 1. I am very happy to have helped you.

This shows you've helped someone but it doesn't matter when you did it. If that happened not that long, use *recently.*

> 2. <s>I am very happy to be helped you.</s>

This is a *passive* sentence, meaning that someone did help you. It's crossed because we require the preposition *by* to show who performed the action. Hence, *I am very happy to be helped **by** you*

> 3. I'm very happy to help you.

This shows you do this often (probably) and it's an habit. For instance, a person often needs help and you're there to.

> 4. <s>I was very happy to had helped you.</s>

First you can't put *to* before had. If you attempt to show that something happened before another action in the past, you can say *I was very happy I had helped you.* (I helped you first and then my happiness came later.)

Another view provided by stangdon:

*I was very happy to have helped you* which implies that the happiness was in the past, but the helping was even further in the past than that.

Comment: I agree with most of your analysis.  I'm not sure the OP realizes that #2 means something completely different than the other three.  Another possible correction for #4, BTW, is "I was very happy to **have** helped you" which implies that the happiness was in the past, but the helping was even further in the past than that.

Comment: @stangdon I've added that correction to my answer as well.

Answer (score -2):

> 1. I am very happy to have helped you.

Because of "to have", this sentence would be used *after* help has been given. If the help is still ongoing, you could use the present participle helping: "I am very happy to be helping you."

> 2. I'm very happy to be helped you.

Helped is the past participle, and in this case using "to have" instead of "to be" provides the feeling that help had happened before.

> 3. I'm very happy to help you.

This sentence does not indicate future clearly. For future tense using will makes your intentions more clear: "I will be happy to help." Alternatively providing a time-frame will be beneficial: "I'm very happy to help you anytime." You may also use **would** as in "I would be very happy to help" since would acts as a hypothetical.

> 4. I was very happy to had helped you.

This will use have as well: "I was very happy to have helped you." The only difference between this and number 1 is the fact that you are not longer happy about helping the person.

Comment: 2 and 4 sound utterly wrong in the intended meaning.